# Sculpting selection problem

Tags: sculpting

I have problem with selecting in sculpting. It only wants to sculpt the last object I selected in Object mode. Here only plane.010 is being sculpted and its mesh icon is highlighted, when I press double A, everything deselect but that triangle icon before Plane.010 name is still highlighted, and so when I select some another than again same problem but only with that Plane. If I select multiple, last one I selected is highlighted and being sculpted etc. What am I doing wrong? [image]

Comment: That's not a bug, it's a feature ;). You used to be able to switch active object in sculpt mode using CRTL, I just tried that doesn't work anymore. The only workaround I see is joining your shindles, sculpting them and separating them again afterwards. Might work with multires, but try it out first.

Comment: I will try that way. I am following https://youtu.be/bWHhx4uos84 this tutorial and on 7.20 he just take sculpting tool and start sculpting them all at once so I was asking what may I have missed. Anyway thanks, I will try your's way too

Comment: I checked the tutorial and put what he does in the form of an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way how you can do that (at the moment) is to actually join them togeher. Select all of them, the <kbd>Shift</kbd>-click on the one you want to be the center and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>. This way they are all one mesh and you can sculpt away. 
If you need them to be separate again at some point, go into *Edit Mode*, press <kbd>P</kbd> and select *By Loose Parts*.

Comment: That will do it surely. Thanks!